# Perform regex operation on given pattern in file using python

Tags: python, regex

I am reading a file which contains 60K JSONs in it in following format:

```
{ "log": [
       {"code": "abc",
         "refs": ["a":"b"]
       }
]}
{ "log": [
       {"code": "xyz",
         "refs": ["p":"q", "x": ["abc","xyz"] ]
       }
]}
```

I need to perform 3 operations using regex:

```
1. "[" at start of file
2.  "]" at the end of file
3. Find pattern: ]}{ "log": [  and add comma in it ]},{ "log": [
```

Note: The pattern is having blank lines and spaces between each characters. No other special characters or alphabets are present in this pattern.

My output file should be:

```
[{ "log": [
       {"code": "abc",
         "refs": ["a":"b"]
       }
]},
{ "log": [
       {"code": "xyz",
         "refs": ["p":"q", "x": ["abc","xyz"] ]
       }
]}]
```

Python Code:

```
f = open('C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/logfile.json',"r+")
s = f.read()
s = '[' + s + ']' # This does not works. Brackets are added to end of file.
```

Comment: So in other words, you have a text file that has multiple JSON objects concatenated together and you want to wrap them in a list (with ',' delimiters between each block) so that the output can be decoded using the `json` library?

Comment: @metatoaster: Yes, you are correct. Thats what I want to do. Currently, if i do `json.load()` it throws `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 16043 column 2 (char 370886)`

Comment: Your JSON has other problems too. `refs` should have curly brackets instead of square.

Comment: Sorry, I added those commas. Basically my intention to wrap JSON objects in a list. Since, I cannot do it, I am trying to add the brackets and commas using regex

Comment: May I know the source of these JSON objects? It maybe possible to add commas while creating the file instead of trying to insert commas later.

Comment: Also the `refs` block has `:` inside a `[]`. Is that supposed to be enclosed in `{}`?

Comment: @metatoaster: yeah you are correct. Apologies for the typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cases where there is a text file containing multiple JSON objects naively concatenated together (i.e. without putting them into a list and thus missing `,` between the JSON encoded objects), the following can potentially help with correcting for that one issue (will not account for malform encoding elsewhere; input from question has been modified to only address what questioner requested):

```
>>> import re
>>> import json
>>> s = """
... { "log": [
...        {"code": "abc",
...          "refs": {"a":"b"}
...        }
... ]}
... { "log": [
...        {"code": "xyz",
...          "refs": {"p":"q", "x": ["abc","xyz"] }
...        }
... ]}
... 
... 
... { "log": [
...        {"code": "abc",
...          "refs": {"a":"b"}
...        }
... ]}
... """
>>> items = json.loads('[' + re.sub('}\s*{', '},\n{', s, flags=re.M) + ']')
>>> items[0]
{'log': [{'code': 'abc', 'refs': {'a': 'b'}}]}
>>> items[1]
{'log': [{'code': 'xyz', 'refs': {'p': 'q', 'x': ['abc', 'xyz']}}]}
>>> items[2]['log'][0]['code']
'abc'
```

The key bit being `re.sub('}\s*{', '},\n{', s, flags=re.M)`, what the expression does (`'}\s*{'`) is to find all cases of `}` and `{` that are only separated by whitespaces (or nothing at all).  The other bit is the `flags` keyword argument to ensure that the substitution is checked across multiple lines, otherwise the expression will match across newlines like the original example.

Comment: Thank you. Solution and explanation helped a lot.